# What is current best practice for setting up an ASP.NET membership site?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity

I need to set up a membership site, where a user is emailed their username and password and then logs on to complete a set of online forms. (It's for an on-boarding system for our HR department, so rather than any visitor to the website being able to set up an account it should be "by invitation only".)

I'm keen not to reinvent the wheel, so it makes sense to use the default templates provided with Visual Studio to allow users to change passwords etc. However, as far as I can see the identity framework creates the user database at run time and stores it on the web server. I'd rather keep it on a separate SQL server - is this a) possible and b) good or bad practice?

My rationale for keeping it separate is that I can then write an application to create a username and password and email the user which uses the same database.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and in my opinion is a good practice to have an Authorization Server decoupled from the Resource Server.

Some benefits of having this model:

- Different applications in the company using the same Authorization Server.
- It's easy to hide confidential users information.
- Develop an authentication/authorization system only once.
- Developers can focus on business and not on how to authenticate or authorize the users.

I'd like to recommend you a link on ["Decouple Authorization Server from Resource Server"](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/). Other posts in this blog are also useful to setup an Authorization Server using ASP.Net Identity.

Comment: Thanks Xavier, that's useful. However - rather than using OWIN I want to host the user credentials on a MS SQL server.

Comment: @Ben Check the post I shared. It's using SQL Server as a DB to store user credentials.